# gobbledygook with WM_CHAR input handling in a textbox

Tags: c++

I'm still probably a suicide at your eyes, or more plausibly just a child who wants to learn how to run a major world-wide company at all costs :L

Trying to make a text-typing console box inside a window, I used this:

```
textString.insert(cursorPosition,1,(char)wParam);
cursorPosition+=1;
```

while getting the *wParam* from the WM_CHAR message of the window.
And when I type in something, I get gobbledygook! 3 letters for every key pressed, usually the one which was supposed to be between the uppercase itself or some strange ASCIIs.
For example:

**a** -> AaA

**l** -> LlL

**\** -> Ü\Ü

**shift key** -> □ (blank) with a bunch of spaces

From what I know, it looks like the text gets not only WM_CHAR, but also WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP. I put the code in a class which is called in the message handler:

```
case WM_CHAR:
myTextClass(wParam);
    break;
```

What's the problem? =_=''

I'm gonna post the other parts of the code if needed.

EDIT: Okay, wait just a minute.
Intuitively, moving the WM_CHAR handling before the other messages solved the problem, but I'm still really curious about why it was doing all that stuff, if not a problem for who's gonna reply xD

Comment: Are you actually handling the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages?  If so, how? And have you tried using the flags of the `lParam` for `WM_CHAR` do decide when to ignore messages, like duplicates and key state changes?

Comment: I have a `switch-case` for the message that handles them singularily; about the flags and the lParam, I honestly don't have the foggiest about how to use them ^^

Comment: in GUI design, MFC/win32 is old. It was a great tool in the past, when there was not so many other tools for windows. Even with more than a decade of cpp experience I still think MFC/win32 is difficult, there is a lot to know. But it's an **old** technology. Don't feel bad if you are struggling. Hundreds of thousands of developers have struggled with it. As I read you question, nothing came to my mind to help. With MFC/win32, I need all the code, I need dozens of conditionnal breakpoints, and hours in the msdn documentation checking for return and parameter values, and forbiden things to do.

Comment: Well, at least you sound, kinda, "honest" though xD looking at myself, I almost see someone that is trying to do awful stuff without having the most basic knowledge.. xd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the kind of thing that goes wrong when the previous *case* in your switch statement is missing the *break* keyword.  So it falls through to the WM_CHAR case.

And using *break*, like you did, when handling WM_CHAR.  So that it gets passed to DefWindowProc() while you really meant to *return* since you already processed the message.

Guesses, you didn't post enough code, but the shoe fits.